# Help proving a statement involving a function $f$ that is uniformly continuous over $[a,b]$, where $\varepsilon = \frac{z}{k}|f(a)-f(b)|$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I recently proved that when a function $f$ is uniformly continuous over a closed interval $[a,b]$ where $f(a) \neq f(b)$, if I am given an $\varepsilon$ of the form $\frac{|f(a)-f(b)|}{k}$, where $k \in \mathbb N$, then the corresponding $\delta$ must be $\leq \frac{1}{k}|a-b|$...here, $\delta$ and $\varepsilon$ are being pulled from the formal definition of *uniformly continuous*, which, in this context, would read as: $\forall x,y \in [a,b] \Big(|x-y|\lt \delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| \lt \varepsilon \Big) \quad(*)$.

Briefly, my proof looked something like:

---

Suppose by contradiction, $\delta \gt \frac{1}{k}|a-b|$. Further, without loss of generality, let $f(a)\lt f(b)$. Consider the points $a, a+\frac{1}{k}|a-b|, a+2 \cdot \frac{1}{k}|a-b|,...,a+k \cdot\frac{1}{k}|a-b|$ and note that the distance between consecutive ones equals $\frac{1}{k}|a-b|$. Therefore, we can repeatedly apply $(*)$ to form the following argument:

$f(a)=f(a)$

$f(a+\frac{1}{k}|a-b|) \lt f(a) + \varepsilon$

$f(a+2\cdot \frac{1}{k}|a-b|) \lt f(a) + 2\cdot\varepsilon$

...

$f(a+k\cdot \frac{1}{k}|a-b|)=f(b) \lt f(a) + k\cdot\varepsilon=f(a)+k\cdot \frac{|f(b)-f(a)|}{k}=f(b)$

So we end up with the statement: $f(b) \lt f(b)$, which is nonsense. Thus, $\delta \leq \frac{1}{k}|a-b|$.

---

**After proving this**, I tried to see if I could generalize that claim to when $\varepsilon$ takes on the form of $\frac{z}{k}|f(a)-f(b)|$ for $z,k \in \mathbb N$ imposing the restriction that $\frac{z}{k}  \leq 1$.

I have not been successful in proving this, so I was wondering if anyone could help me out. Cheers~

Comment: $z/k=1/(k/z)\leq 1/\lfloor k/z\rfloor.$ So you get $$\delta<|a-b|/\lfloor z/k\rfloor.$$ Not sure you an do much better.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How does the floor function apply to fractions?

Comment: The floor function applies to real number. Fractions are real numbers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oh, sorry. I misread that as $\frac{1}{\left\lfloor\frac{z}{k}\right\rfloor}$ and, given that $\frac{z}{k} \lt 1$, I thought "...Divide by $0$?". Thanks~